# Any CLI to validate URL?

Tags: command-line, url

I got a bunch of URLs (more than 1,000) and I am wondering if there is any CLI script to validate URL for http schema?

Comment: If you google for something like "perl validate url" you will get there...

Comment: Thanks. I got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599047/how-can-i-validate-a-website-url-in-perl and it works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by URL? Are you trying to see if it's well-formed according to RFC1738? Do you want heuristics to detect unencoded space and extra final punctuation? Do you want to know whether the URL points to a reachable web page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Perl's `Regexp::Common::URI::http`. From the [CPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2011121001/lib/Regexp/Common/URI/http.pm):

```perl
use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;

while (<>) {
    /$RE{URI}{HTTP}/       and  print "Contains an HTTP URI.\n";
}
```

Comment: Even `wget` can do that to a certain extent (wish I could write an answer here, but the ever-present SE "cerberuses" have chosen to close this question). * Sigh * So here goes ... You may (mis)use `wget -nv --spider <someURL>` and evaluate its return code (`echo $?`). This is only for checking whether the link is valid (respectively the server still up) or not, though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `egrep "^https?:\/\/" yourlistofurls` or do you want to check that that url points to valid http content, too?